# Get specific part of a row from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing upcoming event which takes data from MySQL of another script (in this case, another Joomla extension)

Thanks to Alex Mihai, I know how to show upcoming event:

```
    SELECT * FROM EventTable
WHERE Date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY Date
LIMIT 1;
```

Now I need to show a date of that event in a specific way. I have date of event in a row in this format (numbers as example): 2012-12-30

Is it possible to select only the middle characters (month number) from this row and make something like this:
if 12 = December, if 01 = January and etc. (month names are just example)

For a clear image I am trying to make an upcoming event with this data:

3 first letters of the month in native language, day of the month, event title (event title already works)

Comment: What you say is absolutely possible but I think you should not be asking like this for solutions instead pay someone qualified to do the task for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP you can also do it:

```
$date = strtotime($row['Date']);
echo date('D j', $date);
```

More on date() and formatting options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Simple as it looks. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%M %d, %Y') eventDate
FROM tableName
```

by the way, this outputs `January 01, 2013`

for more formats, click the link below

- [Format Date Fields Using MySQL DATE_FORMAT()](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

Comment: if you want the first letter then you only need to change the parameter of the `Date_FORMAT`.  eg, `DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%b %d, %Y')`